# Pure Javascript full color spectrum ColorPicker

Tags: javascript, color-picker

I did a lot of research to find a full color spectrum javascript color picker, like in the image below, where the users don't have to set anything like brightness, hue or saturation, just drag over the color they need.

The nearest result was this [Bootstrap Form Helper - ColorPicker](https://bootstrapformhelpers.com/colorpicker/), but it came bundled with jQuery and Bootstrap, no a pure javascript solution.

[image: Full color spectrum]

Please check this link [Bootstrap Form Helpers - Colorpicker](https://bootstrapformhelpers.com/colorpicker/) to get the type of colorPicker I'm looking for.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Default in most modern browsers you can use [`<input type="color">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color); You can then use vanilla javascript to listen for change events & capture the color.

**html**

```
<body>
 <label for="colorWell">Color:</label>
 <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell">
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
function startup() {
  colorWell = document.querySelector("#colorWell");
  colorWell.value = defaultColor;
  colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
  colorWell.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
  colorWell.select();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm specifically looking for a colorPicker with no settings (hue, brightness, saturation ...) to improve the user experience. please check this link https://bootstrapformhelpers.com/colorpicker/ to get my point of view

Comment: @cool-man good luck, the best bet is to scan the results [here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=color%20picker)